# Pry in SublimeREPL

Tags: sublimetext2, pry, sublimerepl

Has anyone had any luck using swapping irb out for pry in SublimeREPL?  I'm close, I think.  I don't get an error however I don't get a response when I enter a command either.  It behaves like the buffer is being reset each time I hit return.

---

I'm using rbenv and have set my SublimeREPL PATH as follows:

```
  "default_extend_env": {"PATH": "{HOME}/.rbenv/bin:{HOME}/.rbenv/shims:{PATH}"}
```

Comment: So, the most excellent Wojciech Bederski has addressed the problem and pry is now the default Ruby REPL in Sublime.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting `Pry.config.auto_indent = false` to your `.pryrc`

Comment: Hmmm... it still behaves the same way.  When I tell it to exit I see all my output but not until the REPL closes.  I probably need to tweak some other settings.  It could also be that the SublimeREPL PATH isn't set completely correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Besides Setting PATH in default_extend_env, you have to set GEMPATH as well. Here is my SublimeREPL setting：

```
{
"default_extend_env": {
    "PATH": "{HOME}/.rbenv/shims:{PATH}",
    "GEM_PATH": "{HOME}/.rbenv/shims"}
}
```

You can add the following code at the beginning of pry_repl.py to print out the PATH to check if your setting  is in effect.

```
puts "PATH:#{ENV['PATH']}"
puts "GEM_PATH:#{ENV['GEM_PATH']}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I use RVM and Ruby 2.1.2. I changed /Users/[my name]/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/SublimeREPL.sublime-settings to:

```
default_extend_env":
{
  "PATH": "/usr/local/bin/:{PATH}",
  "GEM_PATH": "{HOME}/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/"
}
```

To get your GEM_PATH, type `gem env` and get path from "INSTALLATION DIRECTORY:" or go into pry and type `ENV['GEM_PATH']`